# sfGuardPlugin equivalent for Symfony3

Tags: symfony

I am migrating an old website using Symfony1 and sfGuardPlugin for authentification, to Symfony3 and I am wondering if there in an equivalent in term of features (permission groups and rights). I studied the SF3 guard, ACL and voters but I cannot find a technology or Bundle with all the SF1 plugin features.

Answer (score 0):

Please check [FOSUserBundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle) (I'd recommend version 2.0) - it's working fine with `sf3`:

- [Using Groups With FOSUserBundle](https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/FOSUserBundle/groups.html)

and other [usefull links](https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/FOSUserBundle/index.html#next-steps).